# Эффективный поиск mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Какой запрос будет пожирать меньше ресурсов?

Есть 58 документов типа:

```
    {name: 'doc_1', exclude: ['ex_1', 'ex_2'..., 'ex_n]}
```

Типов значения **name** - ограничено (58шт), а **exclude** - неограниченное количество значений

На вход имеется значение 'ex_x' и 'doc_x',

Я делаю поиск в БД по полю exclude:

```
 findOne({exclude: 'ex_x})
```

И сравниваю:

```
  if (res.name === doc_x) then {return true} else {return false}
```

Вопрос:
Не было ли эффективней создавать документы типа:

```
  {exclude: 'ex_1', name: ['doc_1', ...,]}
```

И потом проверять на наличие в массиве doc_x

Важна скорость выполнения

Comment: А что мешает делать поиск сразу по обоим полям?

Comment: [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)